# How to reduce expression into sum of partial fractions?

Tags: polynomials

```
h[g_] := (-1 - 19199/12862 g - 12824/6431 g^2 - 56527/25724 g^3 - 
1907/872 g^4 - 11662/6431 g^5 - 9329/6431 g^6)/(1 + 
19199/12862 g + 44865/25724 g^2 + 93855/51448 g^3 + 
11662/6431 g^4 + 9329/6431 g^5)
```

I have to reduce `h'[g]/h[g]` to the form `a1/(g-g1)+a2/(g-g2)+a3/(g-g3)+...` (It can be reduced to this form). How can I achieve this?

`Apart[h'[g]/h[g]]` doesn't work.

Comment: Your denominators will have `Root[]` objects in it since the denominator is irreducible. Are you sure this is what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the desired form, but as J.M. said, the quotent of derivative h and h yields complex root elements.

```
quot = h'[g]/h[g] // Simplify;

quot2 = Expand[Numerator[quot]]/Expand[Denominator[quot]]

(*     (1323448352 g + 3951000608 g^2 + 6903517672 g^3 + 9744056816 g^4 + 
        29820021508 g^5 + 30814028799 g^6 + 27424617344 g^7 + 
        21320832480 g^8 + 13925734144 g^9 + 5569935424 g^10)/(2646896704 + 
        7902001216 g + 15792207872 g^2 + 25414614544 g^3 + 
        35683825156 g^4 + 44217975288 g^5 + 47013763716 g^6 + 
        42866928895 g^7 + 34387484416 g^8 + 24105800192 g^9 + 
        13925734144 g^10 + 5569935424 g^11)     *)
```

Since the Coefficient to g^11 in the denominator is 5569935424, you have to multiply the developing form with this factor to get the same form.

```
 devel = (1/5569935424)*(a1/(g - g1) + a2/(g - g2) + a3/(g - g3) + 
  a4/(g - g4) + a5/(g - g5) + a6/(g - g6) + a7/(g - g7) + 
  a8/(g - g8) + a9/(g - g9) + a10/(g - g10) + a11/(g - g11)) //Together;
```

The full denominator is than

```
den11 = Denominator[devel] // Simplify

(*     5569935424 (g - g1) (g - g10) (g - g11) (g - g2) (g - g3) (g - 
       g4) (g - g5) (g - g6) (g - g7) (g - g8) (g - g9)     *)
```

The roots are g1 to g11

Now solve for the roots of the quotientfunction and asign it to the gi

```
sol = g /. Solve[Denominator[quot2] == 0, g]

(*     {Root[51448 + 76796 #1 + 89730 #1^2 + 93855 #1^3 + 93296 #1^4 + 
74632 #1^5 &, 1], 
       Root[51448 + 76796 #1 + 89730 #1^2 + 93855 #1^3 + 93296 #1^4 + 
74632 #1^5 &, 2], 
       Root[51448 + 76796 #1 + 89730 #1^2 + 93855 #1^3 + 93296 #1^4 + 
74632 #1^5 &, 3], 
       Root[51448 + 76796 #1 + 89730 #1^2 + 93855 #1^3 + 93296 #1^4 + 
74632 #1^5 &, 4], 
       Root[51448 + 76796 #1 + 89730 #1^2 + 93855 #1^3 + 93296 #1^4 + 
74632 #1^5 &, 5], 
       Root[51448 + 76796 #1 + 102592 #1^2 + 113054 #1^3 + 112513 #1^4 + 
93296 #1^5 + 74632 #1^6 &, 1], 
     Root[51448 + 76796 #1 + 102592 #1^2 + 113054 #1^3 + 112513 #1^4 + 
93296 #1^5 + 74632 #1^6 &, 2], 
     Root[51448 + 76796 #1 + 102592 #1^2 + 113054 #1^3 + 112513 #1^4 + 
93296 #1^5 + 74632 #1^6 &, 3], 
     Root[51448 + 76796 #1 + 102592 #1^2 + 113054 #1^3 + 112513 #1^4 + 
93296 #1^5 + 74632 #1^6 &, 4], 
     Root[51448 + 76796 #1 + 102592 #1^2 + 113054 #1^3 + 112513 #1^4 + 
93296 #1^5 + 74632 #1^6 &, 5], 
     Root[51448 + 76796 #1 + 102592 #1^2 + 113054 #1^3 + 112513 #1^4 + 
93296 #1^5 + 74632 #1^6 &, 6]}     *)
```

They are complex numbers

```
sol // N

(*     {-0.93009, -0.523816 - 0.75342 I, -0.523816 + 0.75342 I, 
         0.36382\[VeryThinSpace]- 0.864789 I, 
         0.36382\[VeryThinSpace]+ 0.864789 I, -0.83218 - 
         0.414422 I, -0.83218 + 0.414422 I, -0.248789 - 
         0.902153 I, -0.248789 + 0.902153 I, 
         0.455928\[VeryThinSpace]- 0.838382 I, 
         0.455928\[VeryThinSpace]+ 0.838382 I}     *)

th11 = Thread[{g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6, g7, g8, g9, g10, g11} -> sol];
```

Solve for the varialbles a1 to a11. You can do exactly with Solve, but Findroot is much faster.

```
(fr21 = FindRoot[
Table[Coefficient[Numerator[quot2], g, j] == 
  Coefficient[Numerator[devel /. th11], g, j], {j, 0, 10}], {{a1, 
  6 10^6}, {a2, 6 10^8}, {a3, 
  2 10^12}, {a4, -268}, {a5, -6 10^13}, {a6, -4 10^12}, {a7, -8 \
 10^12}, {a8, 8 10^13}, {a9, -1 10^12}, {a10, -1 10^11}, {a11, 
  5 10^11}}, WorkingPrecision -> 50, AccuracyGoal -> 12, 
  MaxIterations -> 2000]) // Timing;
```

All roots seem to be exact numbers, therfore round.

```
th12 = Thread[{a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, 
a11} -> ({a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11} /. fr21 //
  Round)]

(*     {a1 -> -5569935424, a2 -> -5569935424, a3 -> -5569935424, 
   a4 -> -5569935424, a5 -> -5569935424, a6 -> 5569935424, 
   a7 -> 5569935424, a8 -> 5569935424, a9 -> 5569935424, 
   a10 -> 5569935424, a11 -> 5569935424}     *)
```

At the end test that the two forms are equal

```
quot2 == devel /. th11 /. th12 // Simplify

(*     True     *)
```